Issue rendering circle in firefox
This is my basic html and css structure :


.circle {
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  transform: scale(0.3065);
}
<div id="root">
  <div style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



this is how my html and css looks on firefox
Is there anyway we can solve this issue without removing transform property form container.
I tried applying
.circle {
width: 8px;
height: 8px;
background: blue;
border-radius: 50%;
margin-top: 10px;
transform: scale(0.5);
}


Looks like a pixel rounding issue for FF. The transform scales the circles down to 1.22px and that has to be rounded somehow. Not sure why you need to scale the container but it seems and odd thing to do.

Frankly I might use SVG for proper scaling of symbols.

A 1px element is going to struggle to map consistently on modern screens, where several screen pixels may correspond to one CSS pixel. The system has to make a decision on whether to include a particular screen pixel or not as it tries to create a circle. Do they really have to be so tiny?
